# Using Postgresql is it normal for the master partition table have rows inserted into it along with the child table?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

Using the the example [Postgres Partitioning Docs 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html) should the master table "measurement" get rows inserted when performing inserts after creating the trigger functions and the trigger?

Using the example given in the docs upon performing a insert both the master and the child table have rows inserted. I though that using 
< RETURN NULL > in the trigger function would prohibit the master table from having rows inserted.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @Frank Heikens, the code from the docs in the link I left produces these results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rows are not inserted in the parent table. They are just visible from the parent table because the child table(s) extend it.

Use `SELECT * FROM ONLY measurement;` and you will see that those rows aren't actually in `measurement`, only the child table. `ONLY` says "use only this table, not its children, in this query".

Examine the output of `explain select * from measurement` to see what's going on when you leave out the `ONLY`. It's basically like a `UNION ALL` over the parent and its children done internally.

Comment: Oh god, I have for 10 hours couldn't figure out why my inserts end up in the master table... Thank you, now I can sleep well :)

Comment: I've also spent like 4 hours finding out why it happens.. appreciate!